# C# Read Bytes from Serial with line breaker "\r"

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I've searched several posts to try so solve my issue but I couldn't make it.

So, my arduino is sending via serial a stream of bytes consisting in:

byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5

byte1 is a "\r" character
byte2 to 5 is the value of a sensor value = byte2byte3byte4byte5

Here is the arduino code:

```
byte buf[4];
buf[0] = SPI_RX_Buff[1];
buf[1] = SPI_RX_Buff[2];
buf[2] = SPI_RX_Buff[3];
buf[3] = SPI_RX_Buff[4];
Serial.write("\r");
Serial.write(buf, sizeof(buf));
```

In python I read each line and when the line "\r" is received I can tell its another value.
Here is python code:

```
while (ser.inWaiting()==0): #hold until data is available
     pass #do nothing
ret_char = ser.read(1)
print(ret_char)
```

Python output:

```
b'\r'
b'\xff'
b'\xfa'
b'\x87'
b'\xf1'
b'\r'
b'\xff'
b'\xfb'
b'^'
b'Q'
b'\r'
b'\xff'
b'\xff'
b'\x92'
b'\x06'
```

With C# I'm not being able to read and work with it.
Here is a C# simple code I'm trying to use:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();
            myport.BaudRate = 2000000;
            myport.PortName = "COM15";
            myport.Open();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myport.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C# Output:

```
 #?    ?
 ?n    %
 
 ?B    ?
 ?2
 ??
 ^?
 6`
 V?
 ??
 ??    ?
 ?
 `
 ??
 Q
???3
????
  ??    ?
 ?    ?
???\
```

I changed the Console.WriteLine(myport.ReadLine()) for Console.WriteLine((byte)myport.ReadByte()) and thats the new output:

```
0
1
134
50
13
0
1
98
210
13
0
1
71
243
13
0
```

Does anyonw know what am I doing wrong, and how can I get the value of my sensors: byte2byte3byte4byte5

Thanks.

Comment: Using Console.WriteLine((byte)myport.ReadByte()) it seems that everytime it receives a "\r" it prints a "0" value.

Comment: "I write ASCII and when I read it as UTF16 it does not work - unacceptable"... Is that roughly summarize your question?

Comment: I think the SerialPort by default returns a '?' whenever there is a parity error (see the ParityReplace property).  The 2000000 seems very high for a baud rate, are you sure that is correct?  Did you check to see if you need to change the default Parity, and StopBits?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov how do I read as ASCII?

Comment: @Marker The baud rate is correct but I didn't check Parity and StopBits.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on how to https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+read+bytes+serial and https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+ascii+to+unicode, also I'm quite sure you actually not interested in converting incoming bytes to string but rather detecting separator. Side note: coming up with a bit more sensible protocol could make your life easier - i.e. don't mix bytes and strings, but simply have {message type, message length} header or just pick some well defined sequence as separator - `\n` is either "\n" or "\n\r" depending on environment, using fixed byte like 0 is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();
    myport.BaudRate = 2000000;
    myport.PortName = "COM15";
    myport.Open();

    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

    while (true)
    {
        bytes.Clear();

        while (true)
        {
            if (myport.BytesToRead == 0) continue;

            int b = myport.ReadByte();
            // This should never really happen because we checked
            // BytesToRead above... but just in case
            if (b < 0) continue; // -1 if end of stream

            bytes.Add((byte)b);
            if (b == 13) break; // '\r' in your data
        }

        // Process values any way you want here...
        // At this point your values are stored in bytes[0...n]
        List<String> values = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Count; i++)
        {
            values.Add(bytes[i].ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Values: {String.Join(",", values)}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Marker for your reply. That's what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting how my final code looks like because maybe someone needs something like it.
I'm getting data from an ADC of 32bits with 2.5V as reference and printing it's value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SerialPort myport = new SerialPort();
            myport.BaudRate = 2000000;
            myport.PortName = "COM15";
            myport.Open();

            List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
            List<byte> forca = new List<byte>();

            while (true)
            {
                bytes.Clear();

                while (true)
                {
                    if (myport.BytesToRead == 0) continue;
                    int b = myport.ReadByte();
                    if (b < 0) continue; // -1 if end of stream
                    if (b == 13) break; // '\r' in your data
                    bytes.Add((byte)b);
                }

                if(bytes.Count == 4)
                {
                    byte[] UnsignedByteArray = bytes.ToArray();
                    sbyte[] SignedByteArray = Array.ConvertAll(UnsignedByteArray, b => unchecked((sbyte)b));

                    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                        Array.Reverse(UnsignedByteArray);

                    Console.WriteLine(" "+BitConverter.ToInt32(UnsignedByteArray, 0) * (2.5 / (Math.Pow(2, 31))) * 1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```